# SQL Using OR and IN together

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select multiple OR clause with an IN clause. Below is my expression:

```
Select * from ABC
Where XYZ OR CDP OR Bell in (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4)
```

I also tried

```
Select * from ABC
Where('XYZ','CDP','Bell') in (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4)
```

I appreciate any help provided

Comment: Are XYZ,  CD, Bell column names or values?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM ABC
WHERE
XYZ IN (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4) OR
CDP IN (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4) OR
Bell IN (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Another option](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b7641/3) using an in memory table

```
with q as (
  select 'XYZ' as Term
  union all select 'CDP'
  union all select 'BELL'  
)
select distinct ABC.* 
from   ABC
       inner join q on Term in (TermYard1, TermYard2, TermYard3, TermYard4)
```

<sub>cudos to Joel for further simplifying this</sub>
<sub>cudos to Paparazzi for fixing multiple rows</sub>

Comment: I think you got the column values and literals backwards (see the 2nd snippet in the question)

Comment: ...and with that change made, they can also do this: `INNER JOIN q on q.Term IN (TermYard1, TermYard2, TermYard3, TermYard4)`

Comment: See my similar answer.  Problem here is multiple matches will produce multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

This has the problem of multiple term matches will duplicate rows
`select distinct` would fix that

```
select abc.* 
  from ( values ('XYZ'), ('CDP'), ('Bell')
       ) term(t)    
   join abc 
     on term.t in (TermYard1, TermYard2, TermYard3, TermYard4)
```

Comment: I forgot about `values` syntax. Definitely the most concise solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind putting the same list 3 times...

```
Select * from ABC
Where XYZ  in (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4)
 OR CDP  in (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4)
 OR Bell in (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

Assuming XYZ and CDP and Bell are fields of table (or view) ABC, you can write:

```
Select * from ABC
Where XYZ in (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4) OR 
      CDP in (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4) OR 
      Bell in (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have 2 options:

Repeat the `IN` list item for each column you want to filter:

```
Select 
    * 
from 
    ABC
Where
    XYZ in (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4) OR
    CDP in (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4) OR
    Bell in (TermYard1,TermYard2,TermYard3,TermYard4)
```

Create a table with the `IN` values and do an `EXISTS` with multiple `OR`.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YardTerms') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #YardTerms

CREATE TABLE #YardTerms (Term VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #YardTerms (Term)
VALUES
    ('TermYard1'),
    ('TermYard2'),
    ('TermYard3')

Select 
    * 
from 
    ABC
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #YardTerms WHERE XYZ = Term OR CDP = Term OR Bell = Term)
```